# How to restrict user access to home folder

Tags: linux, centos

I have a centos vps, where i have created a new user with password.
Whenever i logged in via ssh it lands in /home/username.  I need to restrict the access to /home/username and its subfolders only.Now i can read any parent folder like root,var,etc. How can I achieve it.

Comment: If the directory is the users home folder, the user will always be navigated to that directory first and no other users will have access as default.

Comment: @RamanSailopal . that is ok. But wheever that user try to access parent folders from /home/username , they can able to list the contents of folder (ls /etc) viz etc,var etc. ie problem.

Comment: I found that, it is because /etc has permission 755. Is there any pblm if i change the permission of all folders 'other' to 1 ie execute .

Comment: You need to look into chroot then - https://www.howtogeek.com/441534/how-to-use-the-chroot-command-on-linux/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use ssh directly, then you need to create a *bin* directory in the user's directory with the commands that you want to provide to the user (and bash, of course) and use **fakechroot** to **chroot** into user directory. You can copy *bin* dir or just create symlink.

For example create symlink like this

```sh
cd /home/username
mkdir usr
ln -sf /bin/ bin
ln -sf /usr/bin usr/bin
```

And then add to `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` this lines

```sh
Match User username
    ForceCommand fakechroot chroot /home/username
```

If sftp is enough for you, then you can just add this lines to `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

```sh
Match group sftp
    ForceCommand internal-sftp
    ChrootDirectory %h
    X11Forwarding no
    AllowTcpForwarding no
```